# Figure won't show up where I want it to

Tags: floats

This is my draft:

```
\appendix
\section{Grafer}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Graf_forsøk1.png}
  \caption{57\textdegree C}
  \label{fig:f1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Graf_forsøk2.png}
  \caption{51\textdegree C}
  \label{fig:f2}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Graf_forsøk3.png}
\caption{49\textdegree C}
\label{fig:f3}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Graf_forsøk4.png}
\caption{42\textdegree C}
\label{fig:f4}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Grafer/Primærdata}
\label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}
\section{Rådata}
\captionof{table}{Temperaturer for blandinger ved ulike utgangstemperaturer}\label{sophisticatedtable}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}| }
 \hline
Forsøk nr. & T ved tilsetning av TBC & T etter 5 min.\\
\hline1&58\textdegree C&57\textdegree C\\
\hline2&52\textdegree C&51\textdegree C\\
\hline3&50\textdegree C&49\textdegree C\\
\hline4&43\textdegree C&42\textdegree C\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
```

This is what is generated:
[image]

I cannot for the life of me get the figure to appear under appendix A. I've tried h,h!,!h,ht and the figure still appear at the bottom of the page. How can I get this figure to appear under the section that I've written it?

Comment: the only reason to use `figure` is to allow it to move, If you don't want it to move yuu can use tabular directly or a minipage ect

Comment: How would I do that and also be able to add captions to every image and a caption for all of them?

Comment: Take a look at the [capt-of package](https://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of).

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Probably because I extend your code fragment to different complete document as yours are. Please, extend your code fragment to MWE (Minimal Working Example). which reproduce your problem. Welcome to TeX.SE!